# How can I Align this Menu to the Center (Bootstrap 5.3-Alpha)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, position, bootstrap-5

I am having a problem aligning the dropdown menu to the center. I can align it to the left and right (`.dropdown-menu-start`, `.dropdown-menu-end`) but just can’t manage to align it to the center (`.dropdown-menu-start`).

I’ve tried:

```
<div class="dropdown-center">
   <li class="dropdown me-3">
      <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <img src="imgsrc.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2" style="border: 1px solid #808080">
      <strong>Guest</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu text-small shadow">
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
         <li><a href="/auth/registration" class="dropdown-item" style="cursor:pointer">Signup</a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"Settings</a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Theme </a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</div>
```

That is what is in the documentation, with a few different classes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#centered

Comment: To add to that, I believe that there is some sort of clash between classes’ styles going on here, but I just can’t tell what.

Comment: You have `<li class="dropdown">` inside your `<div class="dropdown-center">` This will 'override' the `dropdown-center` class.